# How to prove l'Hospital's rule for $\infty/\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, proof-writing

I'm having trouble with this l'Hospital's rule wiki page(the proof of l'Hospital's rule):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LHospital%27s_rule

Well, in the case where the limit looks like $0/0$, it's quite easy to understand.
On the contrary, the other case( $\infty/\infty$ case) is puzzling. Notations like 'liminf', 'limsup', etc. confuse me further.(Can't understand)

It would be of great help if the proof can be explained step by step.

Comment: take $\frac{1/\infty}{1/\infty}$ and use the $0/0$ rule

Comment: @SantoshLinkha If you try that, you are given that $\lim \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists but you need to assume that $\lim \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\frac{g^2(x)}{f^2(x)}$ exists. If both functions are positive, and the limit is non-trivial, this is equivalent to the existence of $\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, which is part of what you want to get using L'H...This approach doesn't work in general, unless you make extra assumptions....

Comment: @N.S.sorry my bad :)

Comment: @SantoshLinkha NP, the reason why that approach doesn't work is very subtle, at the first look it seems to work :)

Comment: @N.S.I thought it would just work and didn't bother to give much thought on it LOL. Cheers :) and (+1) to you from my side

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The case $\frac{0}{0}$ is an immediate consequence of Cauchy's Mean value Theorem.

$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ can also be proven the same way, but it is a little more technical since you have to be careful with the interval where you apply this Theorem.

Lets see if I can remember it:

**Proof for $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$**

Let $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) =\lim_{x \to c} g(x) =+\infty$ (the other cases can be obtained from this by replaceing $f,g$ by $\pm f, \pm g$.

Assume $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=l$ and that $g'$ doesn't vanish near $c$.

I will prove that $\lim_{x \to c^-} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l$, the other one side limit is identical.

Let $\epsilon >0$. Then, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that

$$\left| \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}- l \right| < \epsilon $$
for all $c- \delta < x <c$.

By Cauchy Mean Value Theorem, for each $c- \delta < x <c$ there exists some $y_x \in (c_\epsilon, x)$ such that

$$\frac{f(x)-f(c- \delta)}{g(x)-g(c-\delta)} = \frac{f'(y_x)}{g'(y_x)}$$

Therefore, for each $\epsilon >0$, there exists some $\delta$ such that for all $c-\delta < x <c$ we have

$$ \left| \frac{f(x)-f(c- \delta)}{g(x)-g(c-\delta)}- l \right| < \epsilon $$

Now, use the fact that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) =\lim_{x \to c} g(x) =+\infty$ to prove that

$$\lim_{x \to c} \left( \frac{f(x)-f(c- \delta)}{g(x)-g(c-\delta)} -\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right) =0$$

Therefore, there exists some $\delta' < \delta$ so that for all $c- \delta' < x <c$ we have

$$  \left| \frac{f(x)-f(c- \delta)}{g(x)-g(c-\delta)} -\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right| < \epsilon \,.$$

Combining the two inequalities you get for $c- \delta' < x <c$:

$$ \left| \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - l \right| < 2\epsilon \,.$$

**Added:** To prove

$$\lim_{x \to c} \left( \frac{f(x)-f(c- \delta)}{g(x)-g(c-\delta)} -\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right) =0$$

Note that

$$ \frac{f(x)-f(c- \delta)}{g(x)-g(c-\delta)} -\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f(x)g(c-\delta)-g(x)f(c-\delta)}{g(x)\left( g(x)-g(c-\delta)\right)}\\
=\frac{f(x)g(c-\delta)}{g(x)\left( g(x)-g(c-\delta)\right)}-\frac{f(c-\delta)}{g(x)-g(c-\delta)}$$

It is clear that the second fraction goes to $0$, the first fraction requires just a bit of effort.

Note that at this point in the argument, $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are fixed.

Now, for all $c-\delta < x <c$ we have

$$ \left| \frac{f(x)-f(c- \delta)}{g(x)-g(c-\delta)}- l \right| < \epsilon$$

therefore, for all $c-\delta < x <c$ we have

$$|f(x)| \leq |f(x)-f(c- \delta)| +|f(c- \delta)| < (\epsilon+ |l|) |g(x)-g(c-\delta)|+|f(c- \delta)| \,.$$

Using this inequality, you get immediately that the first fraction also goes to $0$.

Comment: Could you kindly articulate a little more about the limit being 0? (by using f(x),g(x) goto infty as x goto c)

Comment: @ChanheeJeong Done

Comment: @ChanheeJeong In the added explanation, why is it clear that the second fraction goes to 0?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following proof is a bit simpler than the one given above:

Suppose $\delta>0$ is such that $g(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)^{\circ}$ (which is the open interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ with a removed). Now let $\epsilon>0$, and for each $x\in (a-\delta,a)$, let $\delta_x\in (0,\delta)$ be such that $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\delta_x=0$. Since $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}g(x)=\infty$, for each $x\in (a-\delta,a)$ there exists $\beta_x\in (a-\delta_x,a)$ such that
$$
g(\beta_x)>\frac{f(a-\delta_x)}{\epsilon}\implies \left|\frac{f(a-\delta_x)}{g(\beta_x)}-0\right|<\epsilon \implies \lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{f(a-\delta_x)}{g(\beta_x)}=0.
$$
By a similar argument $\beta_x$ can be chosen so that we also have $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{g(a-\delta_x)}{g(\beta_x)}=0$. Note that this implies $g(\beta_x)-g(a-\delta_x)\neq 0$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $a$. Now by the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem, there exists an $\alpha_x\in (a-\delta_x,\beta_x)$ such that
$$
(f(\beta_x)-f(a-\delta_x))g'(\alpha_x)=(g(\beta_x)-g(a-\delta_x))f'(\alpha_x)\implies \frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}=\frac{f(\beta_x)-f(a-\delta_x)}{g(\beta_x)-g(a-\delta_x)}.
$$
We then have
$$
\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{f(\beta_x)-f(a-\delta_x)}{g(\beta_x)-g(a-\delta_x)}=\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}=\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)},
$$
thus
$$
\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{f(\beta_x)}{g(\beta_x)}=\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{\frac{f(\beta_x)}{g(\beta_x)}-\frac{f(a-\delta_x)}{g(\beta_x)}}{1-\frac{g(a-\delta_x)}{g(\beta_x)}}=\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{f(\beta_x)-f(a-\delta_x)}{g(\beta_x)-g(a-\delta_x)}=\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.
$$
The proof that $\lim_{x\to a^{+}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a^{+}}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ is similar.